# Pandas groupby+transform on 50 million rows is taking 3 hours

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, transform

I am using pandas module. In my DataFrame 3 fields are account ,month and salary.

```
    account month              Salary
    1       201501             10000
    2       201506             20000
    2       201506             20000
    3       201508             30000
    3       201508             30000
    3       201506             10000
    3       201506             10000
    3       201506             10000
    3       201506             10000
```

I am doing groupby on Account and Month and convert salary to percent of salary of group it belongs.

```
MyDataFrame['salary'] = MyDataFrame.groupby(['account'], ['month'])['salary'].transform(lambda x: x/x.sum())
```

Now MyDataFrame becomes like below table

```
    account month              Salary
    1       201501             1
    2       201506             .5
    2       201506             .5
    3       201508             .5
    3       201508             .5
    3       201506             .25
    3       201506             .25
    3       201506             .25
    3       201506             .25
```

Problem is: **Operation on 50 million such rows is taking 3 hours**. 
I executed groupyby separately it is fast takes 5 seconds only.I think it is transform taking long time here. **is there any way to improve performance ?**

Update:
To provide more clarity adding example
Some account holder received salary 2000 in Jun and 8000 in July so his proportion becomes .2 for Jun and .8 for July. my purpose is to calculate this proportion.

Comment: Answer = Request . So mean , create dataset answer every entry for best performance. Otherwise waste resource. Don't iterate your collections. Why google bot visit all web sites ?

Comment: @SDilmac Forgot to add column name after groupby, updated now. Not sure if it was waste of resource as per your comment. And when you say don't iterate your collection , what is the other way ? thats what i need. when everything is in memory why do i need to iterate one by one. but i dont know what is the other way

Comment: And when you say don't iterate your collection = A entry percent of collections(1/50m) so when check total status you scan all collection.
Friend you will be ready to all requests. Create a collection of collections status. Write source and status(regroup,analyse) collection with same time.

Comment: @SDilmac could not understand anything , can you give any example/link what are you trying to suggest

Comment: @Vipin: why are you doing `lambda x: x.sum()` rather than simply `sum` or `'sum'`?  Both the Python function and the string are intercepted and passed on to the fast version of the function.

Comment: @DSM thanks for pointing this , I have updated code. I am trying to use lambda x: x/x.sum() to calculate proportion

Comment: @Vipin: you can still use the fast versions if you follow Jeff's pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you need be more explicit and show exactly what you are doing. This is something pandas excels at.

Note for @Uri Goren. This is a constant memory process and only has 1 group in memory at a time. This will scale linearly with the number of groups. Sorting is also unecessary.

```
In [20]: np.random.seed(1234)

In [21]: ngroups = 1000

In [22]: nrows = 50000000

In [23]: dates = pd.date_range('20000101',freq='MS',periods=ngroups)

In [24]:  df = DataFrame({'account' : np.random.randint(0,ngroups,size=nrows),
                 'date' : dates.take(np.random.randint(0,ngroups,size=nrows)),
                 'values' : np.random.randn(nrows) })


In [25]: 

In [25]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 50000000 entries, 0 to 49999999
Data columns (total 3 columns):
account    int64
date       datetime64[ns]
values     float64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1), int64(1)
memory usage: 1.5 GB

In [26]: df.head()
Out[26]: 
   account       date    values
0      815 2048-02-01 -0.412587
1      723 2023-01-01 -0.098131
2      294 2020-11-01 -2.899752
3       53 2058-02-01 -0.469925
4      204 2080-11-01  1.389950

In [27]: %timeit df.groupby(['account','date']).sum()
1 loops, best of 3: 8.08 s per loop
```

If you want to transform the output, then doit like this

```
In [37]: g = df.groupby(['account','date'])['values']

In [38]: result = 100*df['values']/g.transform('sum')

In [41]: result.head()
Out[41]: 
0     4.688957
1    -2.340621
2   -80.042089
3   -13.813078
4   -70.857014
dtype: float64

In [43]: len(result)
Out[43]: 50000000

In [42]: %timeit 100*df['values']/g.transform('sum')
1 loops, best of 3: 30.9 s per loop
```

Take a bit longer. But again this should be a relatively fast operation.

Comment: I want to calculate proportional salary all account holders received monthly. e.g one account holder received salary 2000 in Jun and 8000 in July so his proportion becomes .2 for Jun and .8 for July. my purpose is to calculate this proportion.

Comment: Being new to pandas and python, probably I am not using best practice here. As i understand in this case using transform I am running loop for 50m elements. Looking at the time i knew certainly it is not correct way.

Comment: I think it's the transform which is causing the problem.  During the sum itself, memory usage doubles and afterwards returns to only a modest increase.  During the transform, for me it quadrupled (so 3x extra) and took 2 min.  If the OP is getting deep into swap, I could believe things would drop to a crawl.  (Plus it seems a little weird that it takes me 8x longer to do the transform than the sum, which should really be just the sum + a repeat.)

Comment: @DSM this is on master, fast transform has existing IIRC since 0.16.0 (maybe before). Transform does memory expansion (e.g. ``.sum()`` then broadcast).

Comment: Plus, the fact that he's using `lambda x: x.sum()` will slow it down another order of magnitude, so if the OP's computer is a few times slower than mine there's only a factor of a few difference to explain.

Comment: ``lambda x: x.sum()`` WILL use the slow algos, would be many orders of magnitude

Comment: @Jeff what should be alternate for lambda x: x.sum() ?

Comment: @DSM I am running it sever and server configuration is also good.

Comment: @Jeff 3 minutes now :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a different approach
First Sort,

```
MyDataFrame.sort(['account','month'],inplace=True)
```

Then iterate and sum

```
(account,month)=('','') #some invalid values
salary=0.0
res=[]
for index, row in MyDataFrame.iterrows():
  if (row['account'],row['month'])==(account,month):
    salary+=row['salary']
  else:
    res.append([account,month,salary])
    salary=0.0
    (account,month)=(row['account'],row['month'])
df=pd.DataFrame(res,columns=['account','month','salary'])
```

This way, pandas don't need to hold the grouped data in memory.

Comment: why do you think it will be faster ?

Comment: the `transform` function passes the entire group the arguments for the handler function, it means that pandas needs to store this data somewhere, This method (inspired by map-reduce patterns) does not store the entire group data, only the aggregates (in `res`)

Comment: By the way, I would assume that for small `DataFrame`s, the `df.groupby().sum()` would be faster